# Make new row dirty programmatically and insert a new row after it in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

I've an editable unbounded datagridview. I'm changing the value of new row programmatically.

Normally, when user types in any field of a new row, it becomes dirty and another new row is inserted below it.

But in my case, when user comes in to any field of a new row, I'm trapping the function key and changing the cell value programmatically.

> myGrid.CurrentCell.Value = "xyz";

And it doesn't insert a new row below it.

Now as a work around I tried this on CellValueChanged event handler.

```
  if (myGrid.NewRowIndex == e.RowIndex)
  {
    myGrid.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex + 1, 1);
  }
```

But it throws error saying `No row can be inserted after the uncommitted new row.`.

How could I tell myGrid that I've made current row (which is a new row) dirty and that there is need of a new row after it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I got the solution

```
myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
```

Comment: I voted for this, but with more testing I found that I needed to ALSO NotifyCurrentCellDirty(False) as suggested by @Haider

Answer (score 9):

I am working on winforms DataGridView. In my case i tried @iSid solution, but here is an aid in that, i tried this

```
myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
```

By only making current cell dirty in not working, you have to commit that cell also. In the next command i am flagging the current cell is not dirty, this will enforce datagridview to add a dirty row. It is working in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think (I'm not sure, though), that you're trying to insert a row *after* the New Row...which is not possible. Changing your code to this

```
myGrid.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex - 1, 1);
```

Should insert the row *before* the New Row, which should work.

Comment: I don't need row above current row. 
I'm changing the new row itself and on its change I need another new row because the current row is dirty after change. I've got the solution. I'm posting it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is really really late considering the question timeframe, but the accepted answer did not work for me. What ended up resolving it for me was first inserting a row above the dirty row, then editing that 'clean' row instead.

```
if (e.RowIndex == myGrid.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    myGrid.Rows.Add();
}
myGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = etd.ResultText; // Edit at your leisure.
```

Comment: Did you focused on the concerned cell before calling `myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);`?

Comment: Yes, the user had to double-click on the cell before the system would fill it. It worked well the first time, but behavior on repeated inserting wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm in web development right now. So cannot verify your solution. :( Will wait for somebody to upvote before I can tick your answer.