# Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

First of all, I looked up this related question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128555/set-datagridview-cell-value-and-add-a-new-row#_=_)  but the solution `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` doesn't work in my case.

In my Datagridview, I have 3 TextBoxes for data input and 2 ComboBoxes for the user to choose the values (which are bound into the database). One of my TextBoxes is set to read only so that the users can only populate it outside the datagrid (with a normal TexBox and a Button).

When the users fill a DataGridView with data, there is always an empty row at the bottom; so I disable this and I used this code to prevent the users from adding a new row inside the datagrid...

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false
```

I only want to add a new row when the users click the button I mentioned above (which throws an error).

The error message I got was:

> "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound"

[image: sample image]
the one with a red arrow is a ComboBox, and the one with green arrow is a read only TextBox

Comment: Are you using the .DataSource property?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It appears as though you are using the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`.  When this property is used to bind to data you cannot explicitly add rows directly to the `DataGridView`. You must instead add rows directy to your *data source*.

For example if your data source is a `DataTable`, using the `DataTable` that is assigned to the `DataSource` property (untested):

```
private void AddARow(DataTable table)
{
    // Use the NewRow method to create a DataRow with 
    // the table's schema.
    DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();

    // Add the row to the rows collection.
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also add at the top: `dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);`

Answer (score 18):

You can get the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` and cast it as a `DataTable`.

Then add a new `DataRow` and set the fields' values.

Add the new row to the `DataTable` and Accept the changes.

In C# it would be something like this:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource;
DataRow drToAdd = dataTable.NewRow();

drToAdd["Field1"] = "Value1";
drToAdd["Field2"] = "Value2";

dataTable.Rows.Add(drToAdd);
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you've bound the`DataTable` to the `DataGridView` in another method and the `DataTable` is not a public variable. Nice thinking!

Comment: Ooo my god It fixed my problem.I've been searched for a long time

Answer (score 1):

After adding a new row, you have to set the row index in boundary of row count.
You have to do these steps.

1. First, add row in DataGridView:

   ```
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
   ```
2. Second, set new row index to count - 1:

   ```
   int RowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1;
   ```
3. Then at last, set the controls values in it:

   ```
   DataGridViewRow R = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex];
   R.Cells["YourName"].Value = tbName.Text;
   ```

And if your datagrid's source is datattable you have to add row in that table.Give new values to the newly added row in data table and at last rebind the datagrid with updated datatable.

```
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();  
    row["columnname"] = tbName.Text.toString();  
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    dt.AcceptChanges();  

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
   dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Check if you have set the index of the new row properly.  Perhaps that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: hi Syeda, just now I tried your method. in debugging mode, the error occurs when it enters the first step, which is `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();`

Comment: i gave samples for both gridview and data table. You tried sample given for gridview while you were using datatable.

Answer (score 0):

The Bound Datagridview has a problem that when you want to add your data programmatically it prevent it to add it directly. so the indirect and best way to add data is like this.. and remember never add data directly to datagridview programmatically because it create problem always, add data to your datasource instead :-)

```
code for VB.NET
Dim r As DataRow ( C# : Datarow r=new Datarow() below codes apply to C# also)
r = dataset.Tables(0).NewRow
r.Item("field1") = "2"
r.Item("field2") = "somevalue"
dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(r)

dataset.Tables(0).acceptchanges()

the update will goes as you do ever
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found:

```
//create datatable and columns
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 1"));
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 2"));

//simple way create object for rowvalues here i have given only 2 add as per your requirement
object[] RowValues = { "", "" };

//assign values into row object
RowValues[0] = "your value 1";
RowValues[1] = "your value 2";

//create new data row
DataRow dRow;
dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues);
dtable.AcceptChanges();

//now bind datatable to gridview... 
gridview.datasource=dtable;
gridview.databind();
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/615379/Adding-rows-to-datagridview-with-existing-columns

Answer (score 0):

When I write this line in Form_Load

```
DGVData.DataSource = DataSQLite.GetData("SELECT * from tableName");
```

And trying to add a new row this error appeared to me

Instead of using DataSource try this code

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataSQLite.OpenDB();      // this line to open connection to Database and DataSQLite class i created it
        DataTable tbl = DataSQLite.GetData("SELECT * from tableName");
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++) {
            DGVData.Rows.Add();  // this line will create new blank row
            for (int j = 0; j < Numberofcolumns; j++) {
                DGVData.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = tbl.Rows[i][j].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

After this code you can easily add rows