# fetching data in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace testdb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string constr =
            @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =     C:/Users/Xprts_3/Documents/Database1.accdb";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Bind();
        }

        private void Bind()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tb1";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for fetching data from database in a `DataGridView`, but it is showing this error:

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound
>   at this line:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
```

Comment: Why is it titled 'php'? There's an unbelievable amount of relevant responses to this exact problem on the internet. Try google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rows+cannot+be+programmatically+added+to+the+DataGridView's+rows&oq=Rows+cannot+be+programmatically+added+to+the+DataGridView's+rows&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.160j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: sorry it is in c#..i have edited it

Comment: Have a look at the anser in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708057/rows-cannot-be-programmatically-added-to-the-datagridviews-row-collection-when

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

First you should definitely separate your calls to database from the rest of the code. Let's create a `GetData()` method that is in charge of well... getting the data :)

```
private DataSet GetData(string constr) {
    //'using' constructs are always a good idea when dealing with database operations
    //your connection will automatically close
    using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr)){
        using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()){       
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tb1";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to bind your DataGridView you have two options:

1. Using the `DataBind()` method
2. Programmatically create the grid columns and rows

**Method 1** - The DataBind() way:

```
private void BindWithDataBind() {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    //call the databind method to bound the data to the grid
    //the grid structure will be created automatically from the datatable structure
    dataGridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

**Method 2** - The Programmatic way

```
private void BindProgramatically() {

    //obtain the data from your OleDB connection
    DataSet ds = GetData(constr);
    if(ds == null) {
        return;
    }
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    //build the grid structure, add a new grid column for each datatable column
    for(int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
        DataGridViewColumn newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
        newColumn.Name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn);
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
        //call ToArray to pass a copy of the data from the datatable
        //(make sure you have 'using System.Linq;' at the top of your file
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.ToArray());
    }
}
```

On MSDN's official documentation about DataGridView.Columns property you can find more info about binding programmatically. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: this method i know but the way i am doing could you please help me in that..if possible

Comment: in this case just comment the row `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]`, and completely bind the grid programmatically in the for loop :)

Comment: it is showing this error ..Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index at line...dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();

Comment: what to do for this??

Comment: This is because you have not defined the column structure of the grid. Before the `for` loop, you will need to add a new `for` loop that iterates through the columns of the DataTable, and adds a new DataGridViewColumn object for each column in your data table

Comment: please tell me what to add..could you please write the code...i  am new to this language..so dont know much about it..could you please write the code if possible..thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Lucian is right you should use DataBind() in that case. But if you want to add rows in your DataGridView in the other way, here's a sample:

```
private void Bind()
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from tb1";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);


    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();

        for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            row.Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Not tested but I think it should work. Just comment for the result.