# Adding row to a DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, rows

Yes, I know there are other posts on this but I can't understand what to change or where to make the solutions fit my code.

**Error:**

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub dsLoadEvents()
    dsConnectionE = New OleDbConnection
    dsConnectionE.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=DataSourceDB.accdb"
    dsDataAdapterE = New OleDbDataAdapter
    dsDataAdapterE.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand
    dsDataAdapterE.SelectCommand.Connection = dsConnectionE
    dsDataAdapterE.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Event"
    dsDataAdapterE.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dsConnectionE.Open()
    dsDataSetE = New DataSet
    dsDataAdapterE.Fill(dsDataSetE, "dataSetEvents")
    dsConnectionE.Close()
    Form3.dgdEvents.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    Form3.dgdEvents.DataSource = dsDataSetE
    Form3.dgdEvents.DataMember = "dataSetEvents"
End Sub
```

That is where the Events are loaded when the program is first opened. I am working on adding things to the database however I tried using the following code to add it to the `DataGridView` but it gave me the error above.

```
Form3.dgdMembers.Rows.Add(New String() {Form3.tbceid.Text, Form3.tbfn.Text, Form3.dtpesd.Value, Form3.dtpdob.Value, Form3.tbal2.Text, Form3.tbal1.Text, Form3.tbpgfn.Text, Form3.tbpgsn.Text, Form3.tbcpp.Text, Form3.tbelid.Text})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708057/rows-cannot-be-programmatically-added-to-the-datagridviews-row-collection-when)

Comment: Like the post says, you're supposed to add the row to the datasource (dsDataSetE), not the datagrid (dgdMembers).

Comment: @Jerrad I don't understand how though.

Comment: @Jerrad Since when I change dgdMembers to dsDataSetE it says "Rows is not a member of DataSet".

Comment: `dsDataSetE.Tables(0)` should get you a table you can add rows to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I load data in a class, pass back a DataSet (we could just use a DataTable), load the DataTable into the DataGridView in form load.

In a button click event we cast the DataGridView DataSource to a DataTable and add a new row using hard coded data but of course this can come from TextBox controls as you are doing.

Class

```
Public Class Sample1
    Private Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
    {
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
        .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")
    }
    Public Property dsDataSetE As DataSet
    Public Function LoadCustomers() As DataSet

        dsDataSetE = New DataSet

        Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Dim commandText As String = "SELECT Identifier, ContactTitle, Country, CompanyName FROM Customers"
            Dim dsDataAdapterE = New OleDbDataAdapter(commandText, Builder.ConnectionString)
            cn.Open()
            dsDataAdapterE.Fill(dsDataSetE, "Customers")
            dsDataSetE.Tables("Customers").Columns("Identifier").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
        End Using

        Return dsDataSetE

    End Function
End Class
```

Form code

```
Public Class StackOverFlowForm1
    Private Operations As New Sample1
    Private Sub StackOverFlowForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ds As DataSet = Operations.LoadCustomers
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Customers")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable) _
            .Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, "Owner", "USA", "My company"})
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above is one method to add data to a data bound DataGridView. We could have the code within the class placed into the form but it's best to separate backend operations from the front end code.

Hope this helps.