# New record not showing when using DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `DataTable` as returned by Postgres:

```
dgOrderLines.DataSource = Program.DB.GetView(view);
```

I have implemented the `CellEndEdit` event:

```
dgOrderLines.CellEndEdit += 
        new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgOrderLines_CellEndEdit);
```

Now, when I start editing a field, the grid automatically moves a "new record" into view that can be used if the edited record is saved:

[image]

However, when I update the "new record" from `CellClick`, when the user clicks the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, it is not added:

[image]

Adding by hand is not possible, because the `DataGrid` is bound.

The code for editing the cell:

```
    void dgOrderLines_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        // Get the edited cell
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgOrderLines.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        string column_name = dgOrderLines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        if (cell.Value != null) {
            UpdateField(e.RowIndex, column_name, cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and, to update the row when using the button:

```
    private void dgOrderLines_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (dgOrderLines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].CellType.
                           Name.Equals("DataGridViewButtonCell")) {

            // art.SelectedArticles[0] holds the articleid for this record
            UpdateField(e.RowIndex, "articleid", "1234");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the relevant code?

Comment: @banging that's the problem, the grid does something automatically as soon as I touch a field. (see also the screenshots; it puts also the editing icon in front)

Comment: `dgOrderLines_CellEndEdit` seems directly related. Can we see that?

Comment: I added some code. But, for the "correct" way, it happens before `CellEndEdit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Apparently, when you start editing in a `TextBox` cell, the cell is marked "dirty" as soon as you type something. So, all I had to do is make my `Button` cell dirty. And of course, [StackOverflow helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497050/make-new-row-dirty-programmatically-and-insert-a-new-row-after-it-in-datagridvie) immediately.

All I had to do was:

```
myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
```

before I start editing and (on `CellClick`)

```
myGrid.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
```

after I write out data to my `Button` column.